# InstallData not working

Tags: module, setup, magento2.2, installdata

I have **InstallSchema.php** as follows:

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;



use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;

class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{
    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        $table = $setup->getConnection()->newTable(
            $setup->getTable('custom_table')
        )->addColumn(
            'custom_id',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            null,
            ['identity' => true, 'unsigned' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'primary' => true],
            'Custom Id'
        )->addColumn(
            'name',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            255,
            [],
            'Custom Name'
        )->setComment(
            'Custom Table'
        );
        $setup->getConnection()->createTable($table);

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

**InstallData.php** as follows:

```
<?php

namespace Namespace\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        $tableName = $setup->getTable('custom_table');

            $data = [
                [
                    'name' => 'Content of the first post.',
                ],
                [
                    'name' => 'Content of the second post.',
                ],
            ];

            $setup
                ->getConnection()
                ->insertMultiple($tableName, $data);

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

I have executed `php bin\magento setup:upgrade` at time of installing.

What I found was Table with defined Schema was created but no data was inserted.

Please help what I am missing here.

Comment: Returning any error?

Comment: it's not returning any kind of error.

Comment: try to remove your module in `setup_module` table and re run the commands `setup:upgrade`.

Comment: I tried that but not working.

Comment: Post full of code, we will look out.

Comment: I have posted my Setup scripts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66640/discussion-between-magento-two-and-deep-joshi).

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below code with sample example:
   Module Name:- **Stackexchange_Test**

Path:- **app/code/Stackexchange/Test/Setup/InstallSchema.php**

```
  <?php
namespace Stackexchange\Test\Setup;

class InstallSchema implements \Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface
{
    /**
     * install tables
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface $setup
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface $context
     * @return void
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function install(\Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface $setup, \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();
        if (!$installer->tableExists('custom_table')) {
            $table = $installer->getConnection()->newTable(
                $installer->getTable('custom_table')
            )
            ->addColumn(
                'rule_id',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                null,
                [
                    'identity' => true,
                    'nullable' => false,
                    'primary'  => true,
                    'unsigned' => true,
                ],
                'Rule Id'
            )
            ->addColumn(
                'rulename',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                255,
                ['nullable => false'],
                'Rule Name'
            )
            ->addColumn(
                'description',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                255,
                [],
                'Rule Description'
            )
            ->addColumn(
                'status',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                1,
                [],
                'Rule Status'
            )
            ->addColumn(
                'created_at',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
                null,
                [],
                'Rule Created At'
            )
            ->addColumn(
                'updated_at',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
                null,
                [],
                'Rule Updated At'
            )
            ->setComment('Test Table');
            $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);


        }
        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am able to create Schema but no Data was inserted.

Comment: ok you are able to create table with columns right?

Comment: Please confirm whether you are able to insert the data directly from phpmyadmin end or using Magento2 programatically?

Comment: I am unable to insert data using InstallData.php in magento2.

Comment: Ok i do understand let me check and getback to u thanks

Comment: have u tried this link http://www.coolryan.com/magento/2016/02/09/installation-and-upgrade-scripts-in-magento-2/

Comment: Here in InstallData.php BlogPostFactory  is required.

I don't have Model in my module.

Answer (score 0):

I just copy pasted in my custom module it's working fine. See below code and screenshot.

**InstallSchema.php**

```
<?php
namespace Learning\Deep\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;

class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{
    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        $table = $setup->getConnection()->newTable(
            $setup->getTable('custom_table')
        )->addColumn(
                'custom_id',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                null,
                ['identity' => true, 'unsigned' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'primary' => true],
                'Custom Id'
            )->addColumn(
                'name',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                255,
                [],
                'Custom Name'
            )->setComment(
                'Custom Table'
            );
        $setup->getConnection()->createTable($table);

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

**InstallData.php**

```
<?php

namespace Learning\Deep\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        $tableName = $setup->getTable('custom_table');

        $data = [
            [
                'name' => 'Content of the first post.',
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'Content of the second post.',
            ],
        ];

        $setup->getConnection()->insertMultiple($tableName, $data);

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

After that run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` command, then go to **phpmyadmin** see the table of data.

For me, it's worked see below pic.

[image]